# ajax loading success response with loading spin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've this following JavaScript Ajax code in modal box:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("BB").click(function() {
var Id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'modal_id' : Id,
    },
    url : "upload.php",
    success: function(response) {
        if(response) {
            $('kk').append(response);
            $('#modal_'+Id).modal('show');
            $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', modal_id, function (event) {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        } else {
            alert('Error');
        }
    }
});
});
});
```

when modal box will open and click on the BB element, then upload.php will be loaded.

```
<BB id="2" data-original-title="Preview" data-placement="top" class="data-tooltip" rel="tooltip" data-toggle="modal">
```

and result will be shown in KK element:

```
<kk><!--result upload.php--></kk>
```

Currently success function is set to KK response and modal box.

Here is my question:

How can I add loading spin when Upload.php is under processing and once the result will be shown, the loading spin will be removed too?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this div (.loading) in your modal.

```
<div class="row loading hidden" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 130px; z-index: 10;">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <h2 class="spinnerH2" style="margin-left:130px;"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></h2>
                                    <h3 class="textH3 hidden" style="background-color: red; color: white; border-radius: 4px;"></h3>
                                </div>
</div>




$(document).ready(function() {
$("BB").click(function() {
    $(".loading").removeClass('hidden');
    $(".spinnerH2").removeClass("hidden");
var Id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        'modal_id' : Id,
    },
    url : "upload.php",
    success: function(response) {
        if(response) {
            $(".spinnerH2").addClass('hidden');
            $('kk').append(response);
            $('#modal_'+Id).modal('show');
            $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', modal_id, function (event) {

                $(this).remove();
            });
        } else {
           $(".spinnerH2").addClass('hidden');
            alert('Error');

        }
    }
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("BB").click(function() {

        //show the loading spin here
        $("#loading").show();

        var Id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'modal_id' : Id,
            },
            url : "upload.php",
            success: function(response) {

                //hide the loading spin here
                $("#loading").hide();

                if(response) {
                    $('kk').append(response);
                    $('#modal_'+Id).modal('show');
                    $(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', modal_id, function(event) {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                } else {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```